# Understanding Exposing Attributes of C++ Types to QML

Tags: c++, qt, hashmap, qml

I wanted to write a pretty simple code which looks for a string and then outputs the variable assigned to it.
I wanted to learn more about the communication between C++ and QML. So I thought of using a hash map in C++ and then use those functions in QML to list out the result.

I had lot of errors so I basically tried everything to make it work and now my code works. But can someone help me in understanding what I have done.

I have few doubts

1. I was not able to access my functions `loadItemList()` and `findcubby()` but as soon as I included the `Q_OBJECT` Macro it started working why ?
2. I have seen in some codes online that they often use something like `explicit Itemlist(QObject *parent = 0);` why and what does this mean?
3. I have defined my Hash map as public variable which I know is not good, can someone show me how would I go about for a private hash map.

Here is my header file

```
#ifndef ITEMLIST_H
#define ITEMLIST_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QHash>
class Itemlist : public QObject
 {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    Itemlist();
    Q_INVOKABLE int find_cubby(QString);
    QHash<QString, int> my_itemlist;
};
```

Here is cpp file

```
#include "itemlist.h"
Itemlist::Itemlist()
{
    my_itemlist["aaaa"]=1;
    my_itemlist["bb"]=1;
    my_itemlist["cc"]=1;
    my_itemlist["dd"]=1;
    my_itemlist["ee"]=2;
    my_itemlist["ff"]=2;
    my_itemlist["gg"]=3;
    my_itemlist["hh"]=3;
    my_itemlist["ii"]=3;

}

int Itemlist::find_cubby(QString Name)
{
    if(my_itemlist.contains(Name))
    {
        return my_itemlist.value(Name);
    }
    else
    {
        return 4;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just read thins: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

Comment: Those are all basic questions. If you don't want to look what `Q_OBJECT` is for in the Qt doc, the first 2 results in Google about it are SO questions respectively named "What does the Q_OBJECT macro do? Why do all Qt objects need this macro?" and "When should Q_OBJECT be used?".  
The same goes if you search for "explicit c++".  
Just set your hash as a private member of your class and you code would still work here.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Q_OBJECT` is necessary as it serves as a marker for the `moc` code generator to create runtime introspection data for the class. Features such as properties or `Q_INVOKABLE` depend on that mechanism.
2. `explicit` is a C++ key word that marks a constructor as not available for implicit type conversions. Generally, constructors that can be called with a single argument can be used by the compiler to convert between the argument type and the class of that constructor.

E.g.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i) {}
};

void doSomething(Foo f) {}

doSomething(5);
```

The compiler has an integer, `5`, and needs a `Foo` object. There is a constructor for `Foo` that takes an int, so it can use it for an automatic type conversion.
`explicit Foo(int i) {}` removes that option, so the compiler will exit with an error, saying that it can't find a `doSomething(int)` function.

3. Use a `private:` section in your class just like you currently do with `public:`